# Cookiecutter template with iso-8859-1 (latin1) characters

Tags: python, character-encoding, cookiecutter

I'm creating my own [cookiecutter template](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html#cookiecutter-meta) for a Python project which is mainly encoded in utf-8. But it contains `.ini` and `.php` files encoded in iso-8859-1 (latin1). This resources must be encoded in latin1 because it's part of legacy code.

When I run:

```
cookiecutter cookiecutter-mytemplate  # <- directory of my project
```

I have the following error during code generation:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/cookiecutter/cli.py", line 123, in main
    default_config=default_config,
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/cookiecutter/main.py", line 91, in cookiecutter
    output_dir=output_dir
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/cookiecutter/generate.py", line 349, in generate_files
    generate_file(project_dir, infile, context, env)
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/cookiecutter/generate.py", line 166, in generate_file
    tmpl = env.get_template(infile_fwd_slashes)
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 830, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 113, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 175, in get_source
    contents = f.read().decode(self.encoding)
  File ".../lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 308: invalid continuation byte
```

Of course, the result is partially generated, and was interrupted at the parsing of iso-8859-1 file (with a "é" inside).

Can I use a pre-/post- hook to convert my resources into utf-8 before template generation and then convert them back to iso-8859-1? And how?

Is there a way to handle non utf-8 files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I store all my `.ini` and `.php` files in utf-8 and use a hook to convert the files in iso-8859-1 in post-generation.

Here is the code of `hooks/post_gen_project.py`:

```
# coding: utf-8
from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals

import io
import os


def convert_resources(src_dir):
    if "src" in os.listdir(src_dir):
        src_dir = os.path.join(src_dir, "src")
    print("src_dir: " + src_dir)

    for root_dir, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(src_dir):
        for filename in filenames:
            ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
            if ext in ('.ini', '.php'):
                src_path = os.path.join(root_dir, filename)
                print("  Converting '{relpath}'...".format(relpath=os.path.relpath(src_path, src_dir)))
                with io.open(src_path, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as fd:
                    content = fd.read()
                with io.open(src_path, mode="w", encoding="iso-8859-1") as fd:
                    fd.write(content)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    convert_resources(os.getcwd())
```